# How to replicate an entry in /etc/hosts file in Django/Heroku application?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a web URL which I can access only after I have added an entry into the /etc/hosts file which was in the format:

<IP> <URL>

But now I want to replicate the same thing in an online django application on heroku.

How do I replicate this with code, either some library on python or some procedure on heroku?

Comment: Access the URL by IP and set the `Host` header manually.

Comment: @Selcuk I guess he is asking something different then setting up a hosting domain. In my interpretation he tries to request a URL with some faulty/missing DNS name.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes exactly, I have an application running which isn't the issue, this application is trying to read another URL which isn't directly exposed to the internet

Comment: I have reopened the question. It wasn't very clear from the wording. Please post the relevant portion of your code, especially the part where you call the `urllib`, `requests` or similar. You can't modify `/etc/hosts` on Heroku but you can use an IP to make an HTTP request.

Comment: I am using selenium, it is for a web-scraping application. I haven't added any code concerning this as I do not know how to proceed, hoping to get some guidance